# If I pass a JDBC Connection object's value to another Connection object, is only one connection open? (MySQL DB used)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

My method returns the value of a `Connection` object.

```
Public class DatabaseConnection
{
    public Connection establishConnection(C)  
    {
        try 
        {
            this.readLogin();  // prompt user to enter String values for user, pass, host
            this.createDatabaseIfNeeded();  // make chessleaguedb if not found        
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection
                        ("jdbc:mysql://"+host+":3306/chessleaguedb", user, pass);
            System.out.println("Successfully connected to chessleaguedb");

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // logic
        }   
        return conn;  // want the logic to handle opening a connection in this class and method, then pass it to a Connection object in my 'menu' class
    } 
}
```

This method is called in another class and passes the return value to a new Connection object that is used from now on.

```
public class DBAMenu
{
     DatabaseConnection startConnection = new DatabaseConnection; // new instance of class that contains the aforementioned method establishConnection()

     Connection conn = null;  

     conn = startConnection.establishConnection();
}
```

Is there only one database connection being opened here, or two, because I'm returning the value and passing it to a new `Connection` object?

I've tried using the NetBeans debugger, and the `Connection` value remains the same after this process, but admittedly I'm not 100% on the meaning of the value column in Netbeans debugger.

(Not using Java EE so can't use pooling, and can't use open source software to handle pooling as work must be my own for year 2 undergrad project)

Comment: Declaring a variable does not make a new object, using the `new` keyword does. Which you only did once via the `DriverManager#getConnection` call.

Comment: And the floating lightbulb above my head has just turned on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I pass a JDBC Connection object's value to another Connection object, is only one connection open?

You don't *have* 'another `Connection` object'. You have another *reference* of type `Connection`. Both references refer to the same object.

Comment: Another user kindly brought this up for me who's comment I upvoted.  I have upvoted this answer also because it has been made even clearer for me (a novice programmer).

Comment: Marking as answer as this was the crucial difference I needed to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You have used only one connection as you have invoked `conn = startConnection.establishConnection();` only once.

You need to implement close the connection, otherwise it will create connection leaks.

You can use like below:

```
try(Connection conn =startConnection.establishConnection()) {
 //actual logic to perform db operations
} catch(SQLException sqlexe) {
  //log exceptions
}
```

P.S.: It is not a best practice to handle connections explicitly/manually like this, rather try to implement Connection Pooling.

Comment: Gotcha.  Was unclear because I created a Connection object in the establishConnection() method and gave it a value - then created a new Connection object in another class and passed the initial value, couldn't get my head around if Java treated it as one connection.  But you answered my question.  Will use the above logic in the code too

Comment: I assume that with _"implement Connection Pooling"_ you mean: use an existing connection pool library.